# The tool called 'at' is not available on Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, server, package-management, cron, at-command

I am running the latest Ubuntu on my server VPS on linode and I get this error when installing cronkeep

> Oh Snap!
>
> at is not available on this system. CronKeep uses this slick command
>   internally to run jobs independently from your web server, whenever
>   you hit "Run". This means you could restart your web server and still
>   have the process running in the background.
>
> Here's the raw output from the command that may help you debug this
>   further: sh: 1: at: not found

Is there a tool called `at` or is this something available on the C compiler?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `at` command (`/usr/bin/at`) is part of the equally named package `at`.

You can simply install it with this command:

```
sudo apt install at
```